# Simple Webcam Streaming Software

Tags: windows, webcam, streaming

I'm looking for some really simple software to broadcast video from a webcam.

PC is running Vista, web cam is a standard MS one.

All I'd like to be able to do is access the output from the camera in a web-browser. I can take care of all the networking, so just need the software.

Anybody have good experience here?

Answer (score 3):

Not used it myself but I think [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) can do this.

> About VLC
>
> VLC media player is a highly portable
>   multimedia player supporting most
>   audio and video formats (H.264, Ogg,
>   DivX, MKV, TS, MPEG-2, mp3, MPEG-4,
>   aac, ...) from files, physical media
>   (DVDs, VCD, Audio-CD), TV capture
>   cards and many network streaming
>   protocols.
>
> It can also convert media files,
>   transcode and act as a streaming
>   server over unicast or multicast and
>   IPv4 or IPv6. It doesn't need any
>   external codec, program or codec pack
>   to work.

Answer (score 1):

**[webcamXP](http://www.webcamxp.com/home.aspx)** is a powerful **webcam** and network camera monitoring, recording and **streaming** software for private and professional use. it offers unique features and **unequaled ease of use** to let you manage multiple video sources on the same computer.

[image]

*free for personal use, compatible with Windows XP, Vista, 7, 2003 and 2008 Server.*

Answer (score 1):

FFMpeg will help you very much. Get it here http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com .
It is a little exe file without dlls, and also works in command line.